# Nodejs, Unauthorized: No Token Provided even though token is present in cookies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication

Even though the auth token is present in cookies and the auth is working fine, when I try to call an API from the frontend, it gives me the error 'Unauthorized: No Token Provided' in the Chrome console. Note: The API is working fine in Postman.

**Backend Code**

authenticate.js

This code defines a middleware function called Authenticate that is responsible for authenticating and authorizing users in a Node.js application.

```
const jwt=require("jsonwebtoken");
require("../db/conn")
const User=require("../model/userSchema");

const Authenticate= async(req,res,next)=>{
  try{
      const token=req.cookies.jwtoken;
      const verifyToken=await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
      const rootUser=await User.findById(verifyToken._id)
      if (!rootUser){throw new Error('User not Found')}
      req.token=token;
      req.rootUser=rootUser;
      req.userID =rootUser._id;
      return next()
  }
  catch(err){
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized : No token provided')
      console.log(err);
  }
}
module.exports=Authenticate;
```

**Frontend Code**

axiosFetch.js

This code exports an instance of the Axios library configured with a base URL and an Authorization header.

```
import axios from 'axios'
let token =
  (typeof window !== 'undefined') ? (localStorage.getItem("Authorization") ||
    window.localStorage.getItem("Authorization")) : null

const axiosFetch  = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  }
});

export default axiosFetch;
```

PostQuestion Function

This code defines an asynchronous function called postQuestion that is responsible for posting a question or query to a server using an HTTP POST request.

```
const postQueston = async () => {
    
    if (data.desc.trim() === "" || data.title.trim() === "") {
        window.alert("cannot reply may be invalid query or add valid reply")
        return
    }

    if (!user.isLoggedin) {
        window.alert("Please Sign in to continue")
        return
    }

    try {
        const res = await axiosFetch.post(`query`, data)
        if (res.data) {

            window.alert("your Query is created successfully")
            setReload(!reload)
            setData({
                desc: "",
                title: "",
                tag: "",
            })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        console.log(error?.response?.data?.error)
    }
}
```

Comment: The way the logic is in authenticate.js you will always get the same message for any kind of error that happens, in the server what gets printed to console when you try? console.log(err);